# Вывести данные с древовидной структурой

Tags: php, дерево

Необходимо вывести данные с таблицы ниже в древовидной форме.
В таблице каждая строка - задача. У каждой задачи могут быть базовые задачи, которые привязываются к базовой с помощью поля **parent_id** (хранит id на базовую задачу).

> id| parent_id
>  1 | null
>  2 | 1
>  3 | 2
>  4 | 2
>  5 | 4
>   6 | 4
>  7 | 5
>  8 | 5

Comment: У меня де-жа-вю. Вы этот вопрос уже задавали? Кажется даже вчера

Comment: В чем именно возникла проблема? Приведите пример кода, в котором вы хотите это использовать.

Comment: Так точно) Сформулировал по-другому.
А кода у меня и нет, есть таблица которую я получаю из базы данных, перевожу ее в двумерный массив. А теперь надо сделать n-мерный массив. N-мерный потому, что уровень вложенности может быть любой.

Comment: Я уже писал, что у вас, по сути, задача хранить древовидную структуру. Хранить массив с дикой вложенностью можно, но это тут не нужно. Сформулируйте задачу __для__ который вы хотите создавать такой массив.

Comment: В базе данных есть большое количество задач, у этих задач есть подзадачи, подзадачи эти привязаны к базовой задаче при помощи поля **parent_id** ( в нем указан id базовой задачи). Мне необходимо вывести их с древовидной структурой, как вы и сказали.

Comment: @tutankhamun, некоторые юзеры взяли привычку стирать свои старые/закрытые вопросы и задавать точно такие же по новой.

Comment: @Visman С одной стороны печальная тенденция, с другой стороны это как-бы самостоятельная санация своих вопросов, что неплохо. Плохо то, что суть вопроса мало поменялась. Ситуация прояснилась только в комментарии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фантазирую. Берем данные из базы в массив `$temp`, например как в вопросе

```
$temp = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 2),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 4),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 4),
    array('id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 5),
    array('id' => 8, 'parent_id' => 5),
);
```

Перегруппируем массив, чтобы можно было обращаться к потомкам по индексу родителя:

```
$tree = array();
foreach ($temp as $row) {
    $tree[$row['parent_id']][] = $row['id'];
}
```

Определяем функцию для рисования "веточки" от корневого `id`

```
function printBranch($tree, $rootId, $prefix) {
    foreach ($tree[$rootId] as $branchId) {
        // Рисуем "листик" (в данном случае просто его id)
        echo($prefix . $branchId . "\n");
        if (isset($tree[$branchId])) {
        // Если у этого "листика" есть "ответвление", рисуем его
            printBranch($tree, $branchId, $prefix . '__');
        }
    }
}
```

Рисуем все дерево

```
printBranch($tree, '', '');
```

Получаем:

```
1
__2
____3
____4
______5
________7
________8
______6
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: Вот же оно! Спасибо большое!)) У меня рекурсией не вышло)

Comment: Можно стеком сделать, но городить массив страшной вложенности тут совсем не обязательно. Задача на самом деле довольно распространенная.

Comment: Понял, спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: @KRasul Только прошу переформулировать вопрос. Сейчас получается, что ответ написан на другой вопрос. У вас в комментарии сформулирована более конкретная задача. Учитесь формулировать :) И вам будет польза и сайт сделаем лучше

Comment: @KRasul ...кроме того, если "с рекурсией не вышло", опубликовали бы код и пояснили что хотели сделать и что получается. Было бы понятнее и корректнее

Comment: Согласен, впредь постараюсь более ясно формулировать вопрос. :)

Comment: У меня вопрос ещё возник. А как сделать чтобы в зависимости от ветки не символ добавлялся в начале, а чтобы элементы входили в див, т.е вета это див, и внутри все элементы ветки и т.д Мне нужно сделать чтобы ветку можно было раскрыть. Я сделал кривовато js'ом, но там ппц все обрабатывать приходится и все равно косяк за косяком.

Comment: А все, сделал, проще простого оказалось)