# PHP Дерево категорий

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, дерево

Нужно сформировать дерево категорий для вывода в каталоге.

```
<?php
function createTree($data) {
    $test = array(
    array('item'=>array('id'=>'3','name'=>'third'), 'children'=>array(array('item'=>array('name'=>'first', 'id'=>1)),    array('item'=>array('name'=>'second', 'id'=>2)))),
    array('item'=>array('id'=>'5','name'=>'fifth'), 'children'=>array(array('item'=>array('name'=>'fourth', 'id'=>4))))
    );
    return $test;
}
function printTree($tree) {
    foreach($tree as $item) {
        echo $item['item']['name'];
        if(!empty($item['children'])) printTree($item['children']);
    }
}
$data = array(
    array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'first', 'parent_id'=>3),
    array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'second', 'parent_id'=>3),
    array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'third', 'parent_id'=>0),
    array('id'=>4, 'name'=>'fourth', 'parent_id'=>5),
    array('id'=>5, 'name'=>'fifth', 'parent_id'=>0)
);
$tree = createTree($data);
printTree($tree);
?>
```

Как реализовать функцию createTree, чтобы она возвращала корректный массив для обработки функцией printTree? В данном случае, для входных данных $data должен возвращатьcя массив, соответствующий $test.

Comment: У вас зацикленное дерево :Р

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Исправил код примера.

Comment: Я отвечал на подобный вопрос вчера http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456260/177613 и нашел еще несколько решений на этом сайте. Воспользуйтесь поиском

Answer (score 2):

Решил задачу следующим образом:

```
function createTree($data) {
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['item'] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item['name']);
        if (!empty($tree[$item['id']]['children'])) $temp['children'] = $tree[$item['id']]['children'];
        $tree[$item['parent_id']]['children'][] = $temp;
    }
    return $tree[0]['children'];
}
```

UPD: Для использования функции createTree нужно использовать массив, отсортированный следующим способом.

```
function sortByParentID($a, $b) {
    if($a['parent_id']==$b['parent_id']) return 0;
    else if($a['parent_id']>$b['parent_id']) return -1;
    else return 1;
}
usort($data, sortByParentID);
// createTree($data);
```

Подскажите, это нормальный подход или есть лучшие способы решения задачи?

Answer (score 0):

прошлый ответ для меня неподошел
немного пределав
имеется массив `$result`

```
  function sortByParentID($a, $b) {
     if($a['id_boss']==$b['id_boss']) return 0;
     else if($a['id_boss']>$b['id_boss']) return 1;
     else return -1;
  }
  usort($result, sortByParentID);
```

далее

```
                    $array = $result;

                    $tree = array();
                    $sub = array( 0 => &$tree );

                    foreach ($array as $item)
                    {
                        $id = $item['id'];
                        $parent = $item['id_boss'];

                        $branch = &$sub[$parent];
                        $branch[$id] = array();
                        $sub[$id] = &$branch[$id];
                    }
```

и все имеем норм